# Access to an element in states

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I'm trying to have access to an element from an array of objects in the React state. This array is the result of a fetch command. I know that I need to write a "map" ,but the map will result in getting the whole elements of the array.

Here's the code I have written :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

// function App() {

// } instead we'll use class component




class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      guys:[]
    }
  
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(user=>this.setState({guys:user}))
  }
  

  render(){
    //we'll add the return part from the stateless component
    return (
      
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.guys.map(guy=>(
          <h2 > {guy.email} </h2>
        ))}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The result of the code above is :

```
Sincere@april.biz
Shanna@melissa.tv
Nathan@yesenia.net
Julianne.OConner@kory.org
Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca
Karley_Dach@jasper.info
Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz
Sherwood@rosamond.me
Chaim_McDermott@dana.io
Rey.Padberg@karina.biz
```

However,I would like to access to only one element,for example, the ideal outcome must be `Shanna@melissa.tv`.

I have tried `<h1>this.state.guys[1].email</h1>`, but this approach seems to be ineffective and I know I should do sth else. Do you have any idea on how to access and manipulate only one (or some) of the states?

Comment: Hi perhaps reset the object?

Comment: If you fetch the following URL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` , you will see the object. I think the reason I can't get access to a single element has got something to do with React Unidirectional feature. Maybe I should somehow manipulate the "map" method. This shouldn't be a complex issue though!

Comment: I dont understand what do u need :(. You are fetching a collection of users and store it in the guys state. So you have an array in the state,  If you need only one user why dont fetch https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 (1 or any id) ?

Comment: you are right. if you enter the URL 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
' in your browser,you will get an array of 10 objects.something like this:
[ obj1, obj2,...,obj10]
each object include a bunch of json data like:
"email" : "info@abc.com",
I would like to know how I can retrieve this big array and put it on my React file and display a property of one of the objects on my screen using React.js.


Is it possible to do so without changing the URL,in other words, is it possible to manipulate and display only one property (from,say,the 4th object) on the screen?